# Let VCR skips URI :

Tags: ruby, api, testing, mocking, vcr

I neet VCR to skip just https://api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred calling the real external API, while going on mocking similar path like https://api.github.com/repos/lgs/elasticrepo

Until now I tried the followings, without any success :

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  ... 
  c.ignore_hosts 'api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred'
end
```

and

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  ... 
  c.ignore_request do |request|
    URI(request.uri).uri == 'https://api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred'
  end  
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`c.ignore_hosts 'api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred'` will never work, as `api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred` is not a host.

For the second thing you tried, the `URI(request.uri).uri` part is unnecessary -- you're parsing the string as a uri, then getting the string representation out of that (which should give you just `request.uri`).  I think this *should* work:

```
VCR.configure do |c|
  c.ignore_request do |request|
    request.uri == 'https://api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred'
  end  
end
```

If it's not working, then it suggests that the URI string is not exactly `"https://api.github.com/users/lapaty/starred"` like you think it is.  You can add some `puts` logging in the `ignore_request` block to see what requests are being made, or you can use the [debug_logger](https://relishapp.com/vcr/vcr/v/2-4-0/docs/configuration/debug-logging!) option to get detailed insight into exactly what VCR is doing and why.